# shiro redirects me back to login.jsp

Tags: shiro

was just tying to integrate apache shiro with another application. but shiro is not authenticating and redirecting me back to login.jsp. Follow is the explanation

I created a test application with apache shiro, that is using jdbcrealm and working fine. the redirect to login page and successful authentication is happening. below is shiro.ini

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp
authc.usernameParam = user
authc.passwordParam = pass
authc.rememberMeParam = remember
authc.successUrl  = /p/explorer

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select PWD_ as password from act_id_user where ID_ = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select GROUP_ID_ as role_name from act_id_membership where USER_ID_ = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = select permission from roles_permissions where GROUP_ID_ = ?

ds = org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
ds.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activiti
ds.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.username=user
ds.password=pass
ds.maxActive = 3

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher


[urls]
# enable authc filter for all application pages
/p/**=authc
```

please note the above configuration is working in my test application (run using mvn jetty:run).

I then copied the same configuration, login.jsp and filter settings from web.xml to another application (namely signavio activiti-modeler), upon accessing the URL it is redirecting me to login page but submitting doesn't result in exception and/or erorr in logs but still its redirecting me back to login.jsp. here is web.xml (shiro is the first filter in filter-chain)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Signavio Platform</display-name>

<distributable />


<context-param>
    <description>Define a reg exp for all user agents which are supported for the editor</description>
    <param-name>supportedBrowserEditor</param-name>
    <param-value>Firefox[\/\s]((3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20)\.\d+)|AppleWebKit|Opera.9\.\d+</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- To load the Spring context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!--FILTER -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>RequestExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.signavio.platform.filters.RequestExceptionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>HandlerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.signavio.platform.filters.HandlerFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.signavio.platform.filters.EncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>
                UTF-8
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.signavio.platform.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description></description>
            <param-name>requiresNoAuthorization</param-name>
            <param-value>
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>ParseParametersFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.signavio.platform.filters.ParseParametersFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!--FILTER MAPPING -->

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>RequestExceptionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HandlerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ParseParametersFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!--SERVLETS -->
    <servlet>
        <display-name>Dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.signavio.platform.servlets.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!--SERVLET MAPPING -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /p/*
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!--LISTENER -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.signavio.platform.listeners.EntryPoint</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--SESSION CONFIG -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1440</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <!--ERROR PAGES -->

    <!--MIME MAPPING -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>json</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ico</extension>
        <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <!--WELCOME FILE LIST -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Servlets from the Oryx Editor -->
    <servlet>
        <display-name>BPMN Layouter</display-name>
        <servlet-name>BPMNLayouterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.BPMNLayouterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>BPMN2BPEL Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>BPMN2BPELServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.BPMN2BPELServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Step Through</display-name>
        <servlet-name>StepThrough</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.hpi.diagram.stepthrough.StepThroughServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>XForms Export</display-name>
        <servlet-name>XFormsExportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.XFormsExportServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>XForms Import</display-name>
        <servlet-name>XFormsImportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.XFormsImportServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Oryx Legacy File Download Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.oryxeditor.server.MultiDownloader
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Alternatives Renderer</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AlternativesRenderer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.AlternativesRenderer</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Oryx syntax checker</display-name>
        <servlet-name>SyntaxChecker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.SyntaxCheckerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Oryx Validator</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Validator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.ValidatorServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>RDF 2 JSON Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>RDF2JSONServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.oryxeditor.server.RDF2JSONServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BPMNLayouterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/bpmnlayouter</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>BPMN2BPELServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/bpmn2bpel</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StepThrough</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/stepthrough</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFormsExportServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/xformsexport</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>XFormsImportServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/xformsimport</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SyntaxChecker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/syntaxchecker</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Validator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/validator</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DownloadServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/download</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AlternativesRenderer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/pdf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RDF2JSONServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/editor/rdf2json</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Please again note that this settings is working simple/test webapplication my doubts are..
client/server redirection and/or filter chain sequence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix the issue by changing the following
/p/**=authc
to /**=authc

after a bit of debugging noticed that authc filter was not executing after submitting the form. The reason may be cause the login.jsp was not within /p/** and submission was not triggering the authc filter. after changing to /** it triggered and login worked.

I do not have the time to truely verify my finding, so please correct me if the behavior is different. but anyways now the login functionality is working as expected.